# CSS, tbody goes up while scrolling down overlapping title and heading

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table popping up in the middle of the screen (position: absolute) and I want, when scrolling down, the title and the `thead` to stick and the `tbody` to scroll. I managed to make the title (tag h1) and the `thead` to stick but the `tbody`, when scrolling down, starts going up toward the start of the div container of the table, overlapping title and `thead`.

```css
.table_container {
  display:block; //when popped up
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 490px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 40%;
  left: 10%;
  overflow: auto;

.table_container .table thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="table_container">
      <h1>title</h1>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr><th>Operation</th><th>Date</th><th>Time</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>
          <tr><td>MOD Request</td><td>2023/7/18</td><td>0:3:8</td></tr>
          <tr><td>DEL Request</td><td>2023/7/8</td><td>10:55:38</td></tr>
          ...
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

The `tbody` does scroll down but the rows initially go up overlapping everything, then when they reach the start of the div box they vanish like they should do right away before overlapping everything. How can I fix this?

Comment: They are not actually overlapping, but rather "underlapping". You will need to give the h1 and the thead a background color, so that that can "cover up" the tbody content scrolling along _below_ them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved simply adding a background color to the title and the thead, since the tbody was underlapping them when scrolling and needed to be covered up.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container-sticky{
        position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: red;
    padding:40px;
  
  }

h1 {
  text-align: left;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin:0;
}

.table_container {
  display:block; 
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 490px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 40%;
  left: 10%;
  overflow: auto;
  top:0;
  background-color:red;

.table_container .table thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="table_container">
  <div class="container-sticky">
  <h1>title</h1>
    </div>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr><th>Operation</th><th>Date</th><th>Time</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>
           <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>
           <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>
           <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>
           <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>
      <tr><td>MOD Request</td><td>2023/7/18</td><td>0:3:8</td></tr>
      <tr><td>DEL Request</td><td>2023/7/8</td><td>10:55:38</td></tr>
      ...
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

```
To made the title sticky, add a div that wrapped the h1 and add position:sticky, top:0 ;

`<div class="table_container">
  <div class="container-sticky">
  <h1>title</h1>
    </div>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr><th>Operation</th><th>Date</th><th>Time</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>
           <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>
           <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>
           <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>
           <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>     <tr><td>ADD Request</td><td>2023/7/4</td><td>17:26:42</td></tr>
      <tr><td>MOD Request</td><td>2023/7/18</td><td>0:3:8</td></tr>
      <tr><td>DEL Request</td><td>2023/7/8</td><td>10:55:38</td></tr>
      ...
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

.container-sticky{
        position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: red;
    padding:40px;
  
  }

h1 {
  text-align: left;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin:0;
}

.table_container {
  display:block; 
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 490px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 40%;
  left: 10%;
  overflow: auto;
  top:0;
  background-color:red;

.table_container .table thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
}
`
```